# Sibling Check Hierarchies on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, cdn, varnish, squid

Can Nginx cache hierarchies in a "sibling manner" like on Squid?

e.g. http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheHierarchy

I am trying to preserve the origin server from too many requests, and ideally it only gets pulled *once*.  Ideally, the system would first would poll all of the other siblings and parent CDN nodes before it checked back with the server.

(Note: One Varnish-based CDN company that seems to do this well is Fastly.  I basically am hoping for some pointers in how to make a Nginx-based version of "Origin Shield" http://www.fastly.com/products/origin-shield/ )

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am looking for the same.

Comment: @SwastikRoy - no , I didn’t